# Is invalid cache actually used or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I'm confuse if cache with status `invalid` is actually used by magento or not ?

If not why Magento doesn't just refresh it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is used In Magento.

Whenever you make changes to products, static blocks, etc, it recognizes that the data in the database is no longer the same as what it has in the cache. Unfortunately, Magento doesn't realize what cache data is different, just that something is different.